# Using the Blitline "burst_pdf" feature to convert large PDF documents to images

Tags: pdf, blitline

I'm trying to use the **burst_pdf** feature of Blitline to convert a 30-page PDF document to images.

I'm posting the following to Blitline:

```
"json" :  { "application_id": "MY APPLICATION ID",
          "src" : "http://mysite/mypdfdocument.pdf",
          "src_type" : {"name" : "burst_pdf"},
          "src_data" : {"dpi" : 200},
          "functions" :
          [{
            "name": "resize_to_fit",
            "params": { "width" : 500},
            "save" : {
                  "image_identifier" : "mypdfdocument.pdf.png"
              }
           }
          ]}
```

I get this response:

```
{
  "results": { 
    "images": [
    {
      "image_identifier": "mypdfdocument.pdf.png",
      "s3_url": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/7N6WmsVu1kHoMQYM79s-Kag.jpg"
    }],
    "job_id": "3zpQhNz6qGYBaPwaj47mpog"
  }
}
```

At first glance it looks OK, but according to the Blitline API docs (http://www.blitline.com/docs/pdf#burst_pdf) I should get another parameter back called **group_completion_job_id** which can be used for long-polling or postbacks once the PDF conversion is completed.

Has anyone used the "burst_pdf" feature of Blitline successfully? Any help appreciated! :)

Thanks!

Comment: There are some differences between different API versions as well, specifying the "v" parameter to use a specific version is advisable. Also, at the time of writing the API documentation was somewhat out of sync. This is reportedly being fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I must have made a typo, or read some old documentation.

This argument...

**"src_type" : {"name" : "burst_pdf"}**

...should be:

**"src_type" : "burst_pdf"**

Doh! :)